# Find the formula for the sum $1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + \dots + (-1)^{n-1}n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation

I was given an assignment of finding the sum of
$$ 1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + 5^2 - 6^2 + \dots + (-1)^{n-1}n^2 $$
Where $n$ is an odd number.

I've already checked the answer in wolframalpha which is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = -\frac{(-1)^n n(n+1)}{2}$$

and was wondering if anyone would be willing to show me how to solve the exercise step-by-step.

I've tried grouping positive and negative terms and got pretty close to the actual answer but then ran out of ideas
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} (2n-1)^2-(2n)^2 = -\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Thank you all.

Comment: Perhaps induction?

Comment: Hint: $(2n+1)^2-(2n)^2=(2n+1-2n)(2n+1+2n)$

Comment: Do you know the closed form for the non-alternating sum of squares?

Comment: Yeah, it's $ (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6 $

Comment: @Vasya's comment shows that you don't need to sum squares.

Comment: For odd $n$ 
$$1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + 5^2 - 6^2 + ... +n^2=(1^2+3^2+...+n^2)-(2^2+4^2+...+(n-1)^2)$$
$$=(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+...+n^2)-2(2^2+4^2+...+(n-1)^2)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-2*2^2*\sum_{l=1}^\frac{n-1}{2}l^2$$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1859620/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2430887/42969

Comment: @MartinR I wonder how did you manage to find [these1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1859620/42969), [these2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588818/prove-12-2232-42-1k-1k2-1k-1-cdot-frackk12) 

Comment: @DarshanP.: With [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%241%5E2%20-%202%5E2%20%2B%203%5E2%20-%204%5E2%20%2B%205%5E2%20-%206%5E2%20%2B%20%5Cdots%20%2B%20(-1)%5E%7Bn-1%7Dn%5E2%24)  – see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969 for more information.

Comment: @MartinR [It's like a boon](https://approach0.xyz/search/), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Snake oil:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} k^2} z^n
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} k^2 \sum_{n=k}^\infty z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} k^2 \frac{z^k}{1-z} \\
&= \frac{-1}{1-z}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 (-z)^k \\
&= \frac{-1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{-z(1-z)}{(1+z)^3} \\
&= \frac{z}{(1+z)^3} \\
&= z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}(-z)^n \\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}(-z)^{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{red}{-(-1)^n\binom{n+1}{2}}z^n
\end{align}

Comment: Hey, that's interesting! $\to + 1$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer assumes that $n$ is even. However, when $n$ is odd, the answer becomes
$$n^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (2k-1)^2-(2k)^2 = -\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n^2 = \frac{n^2+n}{2} = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$$

The answer is $-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ when $n$ is even, and $\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$ when $n$ is odd,  which makes the answer:
$$-\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)n}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Say, for even number of terms we split the series as

$$\begin{align*}
S_{\text{pair}} = 1^2 -2^2 + 3^2-4^2......\text{with even number of terms}
\end{align*}$$

```
+--------+--------------+---------+
|        |              |-1*Below |
+--------+--------------+---------+
|1^2- 2^2|  (1-2)(1+2)  |  3      |
+--------+--------------+---------+
|3^2- 4^2|  (3-4)(3+4)  |  7      |
+--------+--------------+---------+
|5^2- 6^2|  (5-6)(5+6)  |  11     |
+--------+--------------+---------+
```

$$\begin{align*}
S_{\text{pairs}}
& = 1^2 -2^2 + 3^2-4^2......\text{with even number of terms}\\
& =(-4)\times\sum_{k = 1}^{\frac n2}(2k- 1) \\
& = -\frac {n(n+1)}{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S_{\text{unpaired with n-terms}}}
&= \color{blue}{S_{\text{paired with (n-1) terms}}  + n^2}\\
& = -\frac {(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2} + n^2\\
& = \frac {n(n+1)}2\\
\end{align*}$$
Combining both
$$S= -(-1)^n\times \frac {n(n+1)}2$$

Comment: Corrected @PeterPhipps thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have :\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k^{2}}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(k+1\right)^{2}}\\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k^{2}}&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k^{2}}-2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}}-\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(n+1\right)^{2}\\ \iff 2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k^{2}}&=-2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}+\frac{1+\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2}-\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(n+1\right)^{2}\end{aligned}

Let's find a closed form for $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k} $, using the same trick :

\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(k+1\right)}\\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}}-\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(n+1\right)\\ \iff 2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}&=\frac{1+\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2}-\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(n+1\right)\\ \iff \ \ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}&=\frac{1-\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(2n+1\right)}{4}\end{aligned}

Thus : $$ 2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k^{2}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(2n+1\right)-1}{2}+\frac{1+\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2}-\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(n+1\right)^{2}=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(n+1\right) $$

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem right to post a full answer, but as so many answers have already been posted, and as this question will soon be closed as a duplicate, anyway, I hope I may be forgiven for adding to the carnage.

Denote the sum by $S(n),$ regardless of whether $n$ is odd or even.

For every integer $r,$
$$
(r + 1)^2 - r^2 = r + (r + 1).
$$

If $n$ is even,
\begin{align*}
S(n) & = -(2^2 - 1^2) - (4^2 - 3^2) - \cdots - (n^2 - (n - 1)^2) \\
& = -(1 + 2) - (3 + 4) - \cdots - ((n - 1) + n) \\
& = -(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots + (n - 1) + n) \\
& = -\frac{n(n + 1)}2.
\end{align*}

If $n$ is odd,
\begin{align*}
S(n) & = (1^2 - 0^2) + (3^2 - 2^2) + \cdots + (n^2 - (n - 1)^2) \\
& = (0 + 1) + (2 + 3) + \cdots + ((n - 1) + n) \\
& = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (n - 1) + n \\
& = \frac{n(n + 1)}2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650754/42969, one of the many answers to the many duplicates.

Comment: @MartinR Damn, I stopped scrolling too soon! I plead fatigue. :)